# Excel 2003 VBA Locate & Copy to new Worksheet

Tags: excel, excel-2003, vba

Im trying to get this code to find any date within December and copy it to a worksheet within the same workbook. LSheetL is my December tab. Ive got the other 11 month tabs created as well and will have to duplicate this chunk of code for each month, is there an easier/more consolidated way to achieve a month by month scan/copy/paste into appropriate tab? -- My problem is that whenever I execute this code it gives me a "Microsoft Visual Basic - Run-time error '1004' - Application-defined or object-defined error". Any ideas? Im thinking about scraping this code and going with another approach but I'd like to see if we can get this worked out before I just skip around. I've also been told that activating different sheets is not the 'prettiest' method of getting data from here to there, is there a prettier way to execute this function? Thanks for any help.

[code]

```
While LContinue = True

    LastRow = Cells(65535, "q").End(xlUp).Row

        If Month(Range("Q" & CStr(LRow)).Value) = 12 Then

        Range("E" & CStr(LRow) & ",G" & CStr(LRow) & ",K" & CStr(LRow) & ",O" & CStr(LRow) & ",P" & CStr(LRow) & ",Q" & CStr(LRow) & ",AK" & CStr(LRow)).Select
        Selection.Copy

            Sheets(LSheetL).Activate
            Range("A" & CStr(LCurPRow)).Select
            Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
            Range("A1").Select

            LCurPRow = LCurPRow + 1

            Sheets(LSheetMain).Activate

        End If

    LRow = LRow + 1

Wend

MsgBox "The copy has completed successfully."
```

[/code]

Comment: It seems some initialization code is missing

Answer (score 0):

First please post your entire code, this will be easier to find the problem.
Then i don't see when you change the condition of your while loop, so basically the loop never end.

LastRow = Cells(65535, "q").End(xlUp).Row
This line seems wrong to me, the method Cells take two number as parameters, so "q" is problably the reason you've got this error.
To fiw this, use the Methode Range like this : Range("Q65535"), or Cells(65535,17)